# How to get rid of white space between picture boxes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, image, picturebox

For fun I'm trying to recreate the first level of one my favorite games, Fire Emblem 7. I got a picture of the map online. I've broken down the image into "squares" with each square assigned a picture box to display the image. This is because each square needs to have certain properties such as terrain values, units inside them, etc.

The actual image is quite small (240 x 160), so I want to be able to scale it to any user defined value. The size of each square should be 16c x 16c with a scaler of c (all map dimensions are divisible by 16). For some reason, when c > 1, white lines appear between the squares. I've check the code and it looks like the squares should be adjacent with no empty spaces regardless of c.

I have provided a piece of my code and links to the images of different values of c below. Thank you for you help.

```
'This Sub Creates The Map From Initial Image And Assigns Part Of Image to Each Square
Public Sub New(Name As String, Image As Image)
    Dim cropRect As Rectangle
    Dim cropImage As Bitmap

    Me.Name = Name
    Me.Image = Image
    Height = Me.Image.Height / 16
    Width = Me.Image.Width / 16
    ReDim Squares(Height - 1, Width - 1)
    For i = 0 To Height - 1
        For j = 0 To Width - 1
            cropRect = New Rectangle(16 * j, 16 * i, 16, 16)
            cropImage = New Bitmap(16, 16)
            Graphics.FromImage(cropImage).DrawImage(Me.Image, 0, 0, cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Squares(i, j) = New Square(cropImage)
        Next
    Next

End Sub

'This Sub Sizes Each Square With User Defined Scale Value
Public Sub Draw(Scale As Double)

    For i = 0 To Height - 1
        For j = 0 To Width - 1
            With Squares(i, j).Box
                .Size = New Size(16 * Scale, 16 * Scale)
                .Location = New Point(16 * j * Scale, 16 * i * Scale)
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            End With
        Next
    Next


End Sub
```

[image: Map Image with C = 1]

[image: Map Image with C = 3]

Comment: Have you already tried to set PictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None ?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately it didn't fix it

Comment: Declare the *Scale* parameter `As Integer` so the implicit double-to-int conversion does not bite.

Comment: Don't position the controls manually. Use a `TableLayoutPanel` and set the `Dock` of each control to `Fill`. You will have to clear the `Margin` to have them completely fill the cells.